# Change default /auth/login routes in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I don't like the *`domain.tld/auth/login`* & *`domail.tld/auth/register`* as routes for the login and register view, i would like them to be *`domail.tld/ingresar`* & *`domail.tld/registrar`* (the website is in spanish).

What i've tried so far is to set the Route::controller to '/' but it just result in *`domain.tld/login`* so i searched and found that i had to override the login path variable, this is what i did:

**routes.php**

```
Route::controllers([
    '/' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

**AuthController.php**

```
protected $loginPath = '/ingresar';
```

but that didn't helped.

So then i found a post where the guy said that he does this:

```
Route::get('/registrar', array(

    'as' => 'register', 
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister'));

Route::post('/registrar', array(

    'as' => 'register', 
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister'));

Route::get('/ingresar', array(

    'as' => 'login', 
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin'));

Route::post('/ingresar', array(

    'as' => 'login', 
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin'));
```

I tried it, but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: I solved it!, i changed to default the `'/' => 'Auth\AuthController',` to `'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController'`, if someone has the explanation of this please answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use these routes in your routes.php file :

```
Route::get('ingresar' , 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin' ) ;
Route::post('registrar', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin') ;
```

when defining routes in laravel, the second argument is the name of the controller and the related action.
in laravel applications, the AuthController.php file is located inside 'Auth' folder with a path like this:
project_root\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php
thats why we use 'Auth\AuthController' to define our routes.

Comment: yes, i know that, already solved, but want some explanation, see the comment i made in the post.